# IIS Compression Module and Vary: Accept-Encoding Header

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis, compression

Is there a way to change the IIS compression module so that it does not put in Vary: Accept-Encoding in the Response Headers? I would rather it put in Vary: * or do nothing and let me put that value in myself...

Comment: In the mean time, here is MS Connect bug, please vote: http://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/758474/iis-gzip-compression-filter-removes-pre-existing-vary-header

Comment: I've been working with MS directly about this issue, and it has been scheduled to be fixed in the next release of IIS, but there is no ETA as of yet.

Comment: @Dr.C.Hilarius Looks good, thanks for doing that.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Ok, apparently the IIS compression module forces the Vary header to be Accept-Encoding no matter what, so caching becomes tricky. For pages with authentication this is bad, because it will not detect that it's different based on the user cookie. I ended up rolling my own compression in my controller and everything works fine now.

My suggestion- only use IIS static compression, don't use dynamic compression and instead roll your own dynamic compression. It will save you pain in the long run and give you more control.

Comment: Do you have a source for this, or did you just give up finding a solution to turning that off? I am currently trying to enable vary:Accept, or in the least vary:* in my mvc application (where i respond with json or text/html depending on accept) But with dynamic compression turned on, any vary header I set in IIS manually or the outputcaching attribute set, is totally overridden with dynamic compression turned on. Pretty stupid.

Comment: @Martin Hansen: I agree, here is a link to how to do dynamic asp.net compression in your controller: http://weblogs.asp.net/rashid/archive/2008/03/28/asp-net-mvc-action-filter-caching-and-compression.aspx

Answer (score 6):

This issue is now addressed by an official patch to IIS. To download and further info, visit http://support.microsoft.com/kb/2877816

Erez Benari, IIS PM

Comment: Interesting. Hopefully it makes it into IIS 8.5 or 9 :)

Comment: The download link has been broken for over a year now. How do we get access to the hotfix?

Comment: Maybe it is now included in iis?

Comment: Unfortunately, although SQL Server 2008 R2 SP1 is listed among the "applies to" systems, its hotfix download seems no more available. Downloads starts only from 2012.